# What runes do you get for Kennen?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which Tier 3 Runes work best for each of Kennens possible roles in the current meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for AP Kennen is:

- Magic Penetration Marks
- Flat Armor Seals
- Ability Power/Level Glyphs
- Flat Ability Power Quints

For AD Kennen:

- Flat Attack Damage Marks
- Flat Armor Seals
- Cooldown Reduction Glyphs
- Flat Attack Damage Marks (or Movement Speed - But I prefer the extra damage)

Answer (score 1):

To play him "traditional" in top lane, take magic pen reds, armor yellows, and then either MR blues or AP per level blues (I see that suggested a lot).  Quints to taste.  Health, move speed, pen, or AP.

I don't know if anybody is playing him as an AD bruiser any more.  In that case, you would probably want AD quints and reds.

If you mid him, you might consider MR blues over AP.